# Pass data from User Control A to User Control B within a Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

To masters out there, I'm having problem with passing values 2 user controls within a form. I have usercontrol A which has combobox and a button and control B that has a datagridview. Now I want to display the data in User Control B which is in the datagridview. How can I pass the data from UCA to UCB?
Here's the data I want to pass:

So in User Control A when I clicked the button named Generate, it will fill the datagridview in User Control B with the data generated in the GetConvo() below.

```
public DataTable GetConvo() {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ConvoUser", typeof(Object));
    table.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(Object));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(Object));

    var _data = from data in User.GetMatchConvo(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString())
                select new {
                    convoUser = data.actor_id,
                    convoMessage = data.message,
                    convoDate = data.creation_timestamp
                };
    foreach (var data in _data) {
        table.Rows.Add(data.convoUser, data.convoMessage, data.convoDate);
    }

    //dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    //dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    return table;
}

private UserInterface User = new UserData();
```

[image]

Comment: Generally this is done using an event on UserControlA which UserControlB subscribes to - like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716233/passing-data-between-usercontrols-c-sharp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706759/winform-passing-data-between-user-controls), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363159/moving-data-between-two-user-controls-in-winform-application)

Comment: The same way you do with any other Control: you raise events (using custom `EventArgs` derived classes) or use DataBindings. Or both. You can also use *intermediate* classes that handle specific relations between specific objects.

Comment: I see many suggestion to do it using Events but I'm not yet tried using Events I don't know how to properly do it. Newbie here..

Comment: `userControlB.Data = userControlA.Data` while `Data` in `UserControlB` is a public property which gets or sets `DataGridView.DataSource` and `Data` in `UserControlA` is a public property which gets the data generated after click.

Comment: To access controls of a UserControl from outside, you need to make them public, or you need to define public properties to access to them or public properties to expose specific properties of them.

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei. Gonna try that later.

Answer (score 4):

### UserControlA knows/should know UserControlB?

Then create a property of type of `UserControlB` in `UserControlA`, then whenever you want to pass data to `UserControlB`, use the instance which you have in `UserControlB` property.

Which is which? Right, Maybe the `BindingNavigator` and `BindingSource` example is a bit clearer:

```
public class BindingNavigator
{
    Public BindingSource BindingSource { get; set; }
    public int Position
    {
        get {return BindingSource?.Position ?? -1};
        set {if(BindingSource!=null) BindingSource.Position = value;}
    }
}
```

Then when you dropped an instance of the `BindingNavigator` and an instance of the `BindingSource` on the form, set `BindingSource` property of the `BindingNavigator` to `bindingSource1`.

### UserControlA doesn't/shouldn't know UserControlB?

Use events. It's the most natural way. Every day you are using it, like `TextChanged`, `SelectedIndexChanged`, and so on. Time to create one for your user control.

In fact you need to raise event in `UserControlA`, then on the form, when you dropped an instance of `UserControlA` and an instance of `UserComtrolB`, handle `UserControlA` event and set `UserControlB` property.

To make it a bit clearer, again with `BindingNavigator` and `BindingSource`:

```
public class BindingNavigator
{
    public event EventHanlder MovingNext;
    public void MoveToNextRecord()
    {
        MovingNext?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Then when you dropped an instance of the `BindingNavigator` and an instance of the `BindingSource` on the form, handle `MovingNext` event of `bindingNavigator1` and set position of the `bindingSource1`:

```
bindingNavigator1.MovingNext += (obj, args) => {
    bindingSource1.Position +=1;
};
```

Want to learn more about events? Take a look at the following documentations:

- [Handling and raising events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Standard .NET event pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: The event handler in the example is a lambda event handler. If you prefer designer, just handle `MovingNext` event of `bindingNavigator1` by help of designer.

Comment: @james anything that I can help you in applying the solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a static variable in usercontrol and pass data to this variable

in UserControl A or B Create a variable

```
public static string info = string.empty;
```

and before you open usercontrol you must pass data to variable

```
UsercontrolA.info = "hello";
new UsercontrolA();
```

UPDATE

create a static instance of usercontrol in UsercontrolA

```
public static internal UsercontrolA uc;
```

now in you ctor

```
public UsercontrolA(){
InitializeComponent();
uc = this;
}
```

You now need a function to perform the display operation

```
public void showData(){
// your display codes
messagebox.show(info);
}
```

And at the end, after you click button, also call the display function.

```
UsercontrolA.info = "hello";
new UsercontrolA();
UsercontrolA.us.showData();
```

I didn't test the codes but it definitely should work

Comment: What I wanted to do is to display data in the datagridview right after the button was clicked in user contorol A. I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: I strongly advise against this solution, you don't need static members at all. Read the other post.